# Ubuntu 15.04 desktop frozen after login

Tags: ubuntu, desktop

I have just done a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.04 Server. After I log in, I see the dash and after a while just a black screen with the cursor on it. I have updated my nvidia drivers (`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`) but I still have the same problems. I've also removed Unity and tried with Gnome Shell, but none of them work. Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: You should ask your question [here](http://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 1):

if it's a fresh installation that means it still have canonical sources disabled in /etc/apt/sources.list!
try to install xfce4 or lxde , theses light envirments may could work , and then install additional drivers (nvidia recommanded/tested).

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xubuntu-desktop
```

after you enable canonical repositories in sources.list
lauch additional drivers , install install nvidia (recommanded/tested) ,           and then you can reinstall again your prefered desktop env !

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall  ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Make sure you reboot to log into the new desktop.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove everything to do with the Nvidia proprietary drivers.**

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
```

**Start from scratch.**

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-nv
```

**Reinstall all the things!**

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
```

**Reconfigure the X server.**

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver), just a little edited.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm trying it, but it does not find the xserver-xorg-video-nv package. I complete the whole process, but I still get the frozen desktop.

Comment: check this page and try to add ppa. https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

Comment: I'va added the ppa and it still does not find the package. Also, I've tried some of the suggestions from the other post but I still get no desktop.

Comment: please check this link too, hope be useful. its how to fix on 14.04 but maybe usable at this issue too. http://sourcedigit.com/13322-fix-unity-freezes-login-ubuntu-14-10-utopic-unicorn/

Comment: No luck. I'm thinking of installing the desktop version and see what happens...

Comment: No luck either with Ubuntu 15.04 Desktop version. I'm completely stuck :(